# Is there a cleaner or shorter way to display these has_many relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to clean up these `has_many` relationships, they're brutal to look at. Could I put them in a block or DRY them up in any way?

```
# mymodel.rb
has_many :friendships, -> { includes :friend }

has_many :friends, -> { where(friendships: { status: 'accepted'}) },
  through: :friendships, :source => :friend

has_many :requests, -> { where(friendships: { status: 'requested'}) }, 
  through: :friendships, :source => :friend

has_many :requested_friendships, -> { where(friendships: { status: 'requestor'}) }, 
  through: :friendships, :source => :friend
```

Comment: yes. you can assing scopes to the friendship and use them

Comment: `-> { requested }` and then `scope :requested, { where friendshops {status: :requested }}`

Comment: btw, can you upload your friendship model afterwards? its always nice to see different ideas, since this is a really difficult thing with tons of different approaches

Comment: @huanson i'm going to go with the first option by jordan, not the least amount of words but I think the most readable :). And thanks for your comment as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One handy method is [`with_options`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options), which lets you apply the same options to a series of method calls. You might use it like this:

```
has_many :friendships, -> { includes :friend }

with_options through: :friendships, source: :friend do |model|
  model.has_many :friends, -> { where(friendships: { status: 'accepted' }) }
  model.has_many :requests, -> { where(friendships: { status: 'requested' }) }
  model.has_many :requested_friendships, -> { where(friendships: { status: 'requestor' }) }
end
```

I think that's pretty good. If you want you could enhance it with a scope:

```
has_many :friendships, -> { includes :friend }

with_options through: :friendships, source: :friend do |model|
  model.has_many :friends, -> { with_friendship_status 'accepted' }
  model.has_many :requests, -> { with_friendship_status 'requested' }
  model.has_many :requested_friendships, -> { with_friendship_status 'requestor' }
end

scope :with_friendship_status, ->(status) { where(friendships: { status: status }) }
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
has_many :friendships, -> { includes :friend }

{ friends: "accepted",
  requests: "requested",
  requested_friendships: "requestor"
}.each do |assoc, status|
  has_many assoc, -> { where(friendships: { status: status }) },
    through: :friendships, source: :friend
end
```

...but I think you lose a lot of readability that way without gaining much.